# Nuxt - result.forEach is not a function?

Tags: firebase, vue.js, webpack, google-cloud-firestore, nuxt.js

So i'm currently trying to pull data inside Nuxt from Cloud Firestore via:

```
async asyncData(){

    return firebase.firestore().collection('test').doc().get()
      .then((result) => {

        result.forEach(doc => {

          console.log(doc.data())          
        })       
      })
  }
```

which results in the following error:

```
async asyncData() {
    return _plugins_firebase_config__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__["default"].firestore().collection('test').doc().get().then(result => {
      result.forEach(doc => {
        console.log(doc.data());
      });
    });
  }
```

with the error message:

```
TypeError
result.forEach is not a function
```

Pulling data without forEach works fine. So if i specify the doc by the name and get data only for one document, everything works as expected. 
However, since i need the whole collection of the data, i have to split up the data via forEach. Any ideas what could cause that?
Same example works in VueJS itself just fine.

I've used nuxt cli to generate a new project, so the project setup should be fine.

Comment: `forEach` works on [arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach). Is your `result` object?

Comment: Use `console.log(result)` or `debugger` to inspect variable `result`

Comment: result is not empty. console.log(result) works fine, but gives of course only the documentreference back from Firebase. @ljubadr, yes, the data is an array. As mentioned, doing the exact same in VueJS works fine, so definitely something to do with Nuxt and its asyncData call i guess.

Answer (score 0):

First get and modify Your data, then return it.

Modify Your code so it looks like this:

```
async asyncData () {

    let data = []

    await firebase.firestore()
    .collection('test')
    .doc()
    .get()
    .then((result) => {
      result.forEach(doc => {

        data.push(doc.data())    

      })       
    })

    return data
}
```